# Programmatically set images in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I am creating android app with Programmatically set images in HorizontalScrollView and click image in HorizontalScrollView that image display in large Image view don't know how to create it help me to complete my code

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

Here Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private TextView deis;
    private Button choose;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private LinearLayout mlinear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        deis=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        choose=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(data.getClipData() != null){
                int totalItemsSelected = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                for(int i = 0; i < totalItemsSelected; i++){

                    Uri fileUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    mlinear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);




                }
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected Multiple Files"+fileUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Complete my code its very helpul for me

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to your code.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear);
1-create an instance of ImageView
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
//find resource from uril
int imageResource = 
getResources().getIdentifier(fileUri,null,getPackageName());
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
image.setImageDrawable(res);
//this will add the imageto the layout.
linearLayout.addView(image);
```

Comment: getResources().getIdentifier(fileUri,null,getPackageName());
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{